# Username availability check using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

I'm currently trying to develop a small website in PHP to test my skills.
However I found myself stuck when I decided to implement a live username availability check for the sign up process, as my JavaScript knowledge is somewhat basic.

Right now when I put some name in the username field, I only get the loading image and nothing else. This is what I have done:

My login.php page stored in the /views folder:

```
<section>
    <div>
        <form action="?action=login" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username" onkeypress ="check()">
            <span id="usernameStatus"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

My js file stored in /views/js:

```
function check () {
    var status = document.getElementById('usernameStatus');
    var u = document.getElementById('username').value;
    if(u != ""){
        status.innerHTML = '<img src="views/img/wait.gif" alt="" height="20" />';
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST", "../login.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
            }
        }

        var v = "checkName="+u;
        hr.send(v);

    }
}
```

And finally the loginController.php stored in /controllers:

```
    public function run() {
        if(!empty($_POST["checkName"])){
            $name= htmlentities($_POST["checkName"]);
            if(Db::getInstance()->username_ok($name)){
                echo ("<strong>" . $name . "</strong> unavailable");
            }
            else{
                echo ("<strong>" . $name . "</strong> available");
            }
        }
        require_once('views/login.php');
    }
```

Could someone explain me what have I done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is triggering your JavaScript? Do you have an event listener registered on the input field?

Comment: Have you checked the AJAX op in your browser's network viewer? Look at the request parameters, response code and response text to aid your debugging.

Comment: hi thaks for the replies. In the debug i have `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS".` I think the problem is the js file not connecting the the loginController.php, but i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: fixed the 404 error by changing the path to controllers/loginController.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with filenames.

From your question, I guess the file structure is

```
root
|-- controllers
|   `-- loginController.php
`-- views
    `-- js
        `-- script.js
```

In your JavaScript code which is in the file `views/js/scriptname.js`,

```
hr.open("POST", "../login.php", true);
```

request is sent to the file `login.php`.

But, as you have mentioned, the path to your server side php script is `/controllers/loginController.php`.

According to me, the JavaScript code should be as following:

```
hr.open("POST", "controllers/loginController.php", true);
```

Comment: you were right about that mistake of mine, however for some reason when i use my browser debuger it says `POST http://localhost/controllers/LoginController.php 404 (Not Found)`.

Comment: fixed the 404 error by changing the path to controllers/loginController.php.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [tutorial](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-check-live-username-availability-with-jquery-php_819.html) that will help you, its a live username checker with PHP and jquery.

Comment: thanks. i'll check this and try to adapt it to my code.